# Remove jQuery event listener when the handler needs to receive a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a listener:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e){ebClose(e,mpClose)});
```

I am trying to figure out how to delete it dynamically.  The challenge is that I really want ebClose to receive mpClose as a callback function, because in other instances ebClose would receive different callback functions.

What ebClose does is this:

```
function ebClose(e, callback){
    if (e.which == 13){
        callback();
    }
}
```

Which is to say, it checks if it is the `enter` key, and then calls the callback function.  In theory, I could make 10 different versions of ebClose and paste in the different functions to avoid needing a callback, but it seems like it is a lot of code.  Any suggestions out there for a strategy to be able to delete this listener when needed?

This obviously doesn't work:

```
$(document).off("keypress", function(e){ebClose(e,mpClose)});
```

And if I change it to this:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ebClose);
```

Then I can delete it, but don't know how to pass the callback.  Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Che bind() http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data

Comment: But then `unbind` runs into the same problem that it doesn't work for unnamed handlers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to [namespace the events](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3tzhh31/)

```
// Attach a keypress event namespaced to 'ebclose'
$(document).on("keypress.ebclose", function(e) {
  ebClose(e, mpClose)
});

// Remove the namespaced event:
$(document).off("keypress.ebclose");
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use [`$.proxy()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to bind the function:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7hjkru8/)

```
$(document).on("keypress", $.proxy(ebClose, this, mpClose));

function ebClose(callback, e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        callback();
    }
}
function mpClose () {
    alert('Remove the event listener');
    $(document).off("keypress", $.proxy(ebClose, this, mpClose));
}
```

Or, similarly, you could use the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mp6ztma/)

```
$(document).on("keypress", ebClose.bind(this, mpClose));

function ebClose(callback, e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        callback();
    }
}
function mpClose () {
    alert('Remove the event listener');
    $(document).off("keypress", ebClose.bind(this, mpClose));
}
```

Comment: This works well, as long as you make sure the namespace comes *after* the event (my first mistake while trying to replicate this).  Contrived example: http://jsfiddle.net/eda78wsd/

Comment: Thanks for the comments- unfortunately I am having trouble getting this to work.  Does .off(namespace) have to come inside the namespace .on(namespace) function?  I am trying to call them in different functions and it just doesn't seem to be going away!    I am sure it is something silly I am missing

Comment: @user3398945 I added an example (hopefully that helps). I also added two additional alternatives with example as well. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  The `.bind()` method is working great.  For some reason the namespace one continues to not work, even though I literally copied it from your fiddle.  I'll have to think through why it works in your fiddle, but doesn't work in exactly the same positions as the working `.bind()` code.

Comment: And now namespace works too.  I think the gremlins are on lunch break, need to work fast.